# lightning-formatted-time with only HH:MM

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, formatting

Trying to display the Time in LWC component by using `lightning-formatted-time`, by default it print HH:MM:SS

I would like to print only HH:MM

```
<lightning-formatted-time value={stime.Start_Time__c}> </lightning-formatted-time> -
<lightning-formatted-time value={stime.End_Time__c}></lightning-formatted-time>
```

the Above code print as below

`12:00:00 AM -12:30:00 AM` Excepted is to print `12:00 AM -12:30 AM`

Gone through the documents, I dont see any attributes supported for this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-time/documentation

Can Anyone help me on this, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard component does not support this. You need to use the Internationalization Properties. Create a custom component like below. And use that instead of the standard formatted time.

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import LOCALE from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';

export default class CustomFormattedTime extends LightningElement {
    number = 123456.78;
    formattedNumber = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(LOCALE, { hour:"numeric", minute: "numeric", hour12: false}).format(this.number);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    {formattedNumber}
</template>
```

[Here is the playground example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lv7DQ7kfwtb3dwnSo6ch). You can customize it further if needed.

[References for Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)